# sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice.ChoiceType проблемы при db upgrade

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3, sqlalchemy

Здравствуйте.

Как бы ни пробовал применить sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice.ChoiceType в моделях SQLAlchemy, так ничего и не вышло.

Если делаю, как указано в документации:

```
class User(Base):
    TYPES = [
        (u'admin', u'Admin'),
        (u'regular-user', u'Regular user')
    ]

    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(255))
    type = sa.Column(ChoiceType(TYPES))
```

то, в версии миграции формируется такая строка:

```
sa.Column('type', sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice.ChoiceType(length=255), nullable=True),
```

и ошибка такая:

```
TypeError: <flask_script.commands.Command object at 0x7f90349e0dd8>: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'length'
```

[тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330578/error-at-migrating-in-flask-with-sqlalchemy-utils-choicetype) советуют сделать так: `sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice.ChoiceType(User.ROLES)`

но в этом случае ругается на импорт User, т.к. в версии миграции указан 'user'.

[тут](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/issues/116)

рекомендуют сделать так:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum
from .db import Base

class MyModel(Base):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('published', 'Published'),
        ('hidden', 'Hidden'),
    )
    STATUSES = tuple(c[0] for c in STATUS_CHOICES)

    status = Column(
        ChoiceType(impl=Enum(*STATUSES, name='mymodel_status'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES),
        default='published',
        nullable=False
    )
```

и это больше похоже на правду,так как формируется такая строка в версии миграции:

`sa.Column('type', sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice.ChoiceType(('google adwords', 'yandex direct')), nullable=False)`,

но в этом случае я получаю такую ошибку:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 14; 2 is required
```

Использую SQLite3 на деве. Возможно проблемы связаны с этим, но нигде в документации не указано, что это может вызывать проблемы.

Конечно же, можно сослаться на таблицу, в которой будут указаны нужные типы, как я делал уже до этого, но этот путь мне не очень нравится. Всё таки, хотелось бы использовать sqlalchemy_utils в полной мере.

Если кто-то сталкивался и знает как решить данную проблему, буду крайне благодарен за любую помощь или наводку.